# Передача параметров в KNeighborsClassifier

Tags: python, scipy

У меня есть код, который задает классификатор KNeighborsClassifier

```
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=2, weights=my_distance)
```

функция my_distance возвращает расстояния до точек с учетом ядра, являющегося полиномом, коэффициенты которого я хочу оптимизировать для нахождения максимума score() на тестовой выборке

```
def my_distance(weights):
    weights_new = []
    print(weights,'old')
    for i in weights:

        # Функция весов, параметры которой мы будем оптимизировать
        # будем рассматривать функции, являющиеся полиномами вида x^(-4) до x^4
        # каждый вес это массив, состоящий из расстояний до всех уже созданных соседей
        w = []
        for x in i:
            if x!=0:
                w.append(c[4]+x**(-4)*c[0]+x**(-3)*c[1]+x**(-2)*c[2]+x**(-1)*c[3]+x**(4)*c[8]+x**(3)*c[7]+x**(2)*c[6]+x*c[5])
            else:
                w.append(0)                   
        #Изменяем веса
        weights_new.append(w)
    print(weights_new)
    return weights_new
```

Проблема в том, что, либо в функцию my_distance нельзя передать более одного параметра, либо я это делаю некорректно

```
def func_opt(c):
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=2, weights=my_distance)
    knn.fit(X_train,y_train)
    return -knn.score(X_test,y_test)
```

поскольку далее решение можно было бы найти при помощи optimize.minimize(func_opt, c)

подскажите, как решить проблему

Comment: Чему равны значения weights и weights_new?

Comment: weights это параметр, который задается в KNeighborsClassifier, на входе это массив в каждом элементе которого содержится массив расстояний от элемента X_test до ближайших n_neighbors элементов X_train, а weights_new - преобразованный массив weights, где вместо расстояния стоит значение некоторой функции от этого расстояния, которую я и хочу подобрать при помощи решения задачи оптимизации,

Comment: Я теорию понимаю. Я задавал вопрос - какие данные реально вы передаете и какие получаете. Кстати, и знания массива с нам неизвестны.  Если мне не изменяет память, то веса должны подчиняться дополнительным ограничениям.  Мы ведь даже не знаем, что у вас не получается.  Вот и приходиться "на ощупь" пытаться определить, что-же у вас не то.

Comment: `df1 = pd.DataFrame({'feature1':[1,3,3,4,5], 'response':[1,1,1,2,2]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'feature1':[2,2,6,7,8], 'response':[1,1,2,2,2]})
y_train = df1.response
# [1,1,1,2,2]
X_train = df1[['feature1']]
# [1,3,3,4,5]
y_test = df2.response
X_test = df2[['feature1']]`

Далее, в функции my_distance у меня не получается указать второй параметр, который задавал бы коэффициенты c, а, если его не указывать, то `optimize` не проводит оптимизацию, что вполне логично.

Comment: Еще раз.  В параметре weights задается имя  "user-defined function which accepts an array of distances, and returns an array of the same shape containing the weights." Мой вопрос был, какие данные вы подаете на вход функции my_distance ? Или с этим у вас проблем нет ?

Comment: на вход функции my_distance подается только массив расстояний для каждой точки X_test до n ближайших соседей, если передавать еще другой параметр, то возникает ошибка при вызове функции

Comment: Ну, так написано же в документации, что на вход - единственный массив.  Это понятно. Как еще может быть?  Вопрос-то в чем состоял?

Comment: Вопрос в том, как обойти это ограничение и сделать функцию весов зависимой от еще одного параметра для того, чтобы ее можно было оптимизировать

Comment: Сколько данных у вас в реальном датасете?

Comment: 9000 строк, два признака координат и 1 признак класса

Comment: И как вы при таких объемах информации в принципе представляете ваш подход. minimize - по сути это цикл с десятками тысяч проходов.   Сама функция - по сути полином 8-й степени, значит весьма не устойчив, значит проходов может быть еще больше, чем для гладких функций. На каждом проходе - у вас - классификация датасета на 9000 элементов, который относится к классу "жадных" алгоритмов .  Что-то тут в корне не верно с архитектурно-алгоритмическим решением.